# having trouble with div layout not going where they should

Tags: css, layout, html

EDIT**the issue apparently comes down to the fact that, i need to use relative position on the large image, so i can adjust the top value. this causes the thumbs to be put on top of the main image. When i remove the relative positioning of the main image, the flow looks fine, but the top positioning is disregarded- i sort of need both to have the dynamic manipulation of this app im developing**

I wish I could understand why this happens like 90% of the time I go to code div layouts.

You have content in your div with a certain height, and then you have another div directly after it - and somehow it just goes right on top of the first one.

I wish I knew where the problem was, but I can't figure out what CSS is the cause.

Anyways, if you care to take a look, this is the sandbox of the issue I'm having:
**the reference is changing because i keep updating it to check sorry.**
http://www.drewswinson.com/DP/

I'm making a dynamic jQuery gallery viewer and the thumbs just don't want to put themselves below the image.

It happens all the time though; is there any reason content inside a div would allow subsequent divs to not be placed below the content its supposed to be filled?

Comment: Your problem is unclear to me. Unless the answer below has solved it for you, you're going to need to explain a little more; particularly: what should the end result be?

Comment: ok sorry, i was updating the files based on suggestions, so i updated my question a bit more

Answer (score 0):

You problem is the position: relative attribute on imageDiv.
It pushes the image down from where it should be. If you remove that, the static flow of the page will be used, which is what you want in this case.

Comment: Just noticed, in order to use z-order, you need all divs with the z-order property to be positioned relative or absolute. So you can remove the inline property of top: 85px; and leave the position: relative in there.

Comment: if i do this, it wont follow top/left/etc values, can i not have both?

Comment: I have several thoughts, but I can`t test them right now. This is off the top of my head. You can add a position relative to the thumbs tag, that might get it in line. You can add a display: block to imageDiv, that might also fix the issue.